# Exporting specific content of an outlook E-mail into Excel when e-mail structure varies slightly every time

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

We have an internship application form (through formsite.com) that prospective interns fill and submit. All submissions are received in MS Excel in the form of a table. However, there are some degrees / specialisations for which we have additional questions in the form and hence the structure of the e-mail received remains the same but the number of rows in the table could be different (according to the number of questions the applicant has to answer).

Since there are thousands of these applications I have been trying out codes to export this content into Excel. I tried the following code in Excel but need to figure out how to adjust it for varying number of rows - if I input the maximum number of rows, it doesn't import emails with lesser number of rows in them:

```
Sub ParseEmailFolderToExcel()
    Set objApp = Application
    Dim olns As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myinbox = olns.PickFolder
    Dim XLApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim EachElement()
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient

    Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err Then
       ExcelWasNotRunning = True
       Set XLApp = New Excel.Application
       XLApp.Visible = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set wkb = XLApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    With wks
        StartCount = 1 'how many emails (start at 1 to leave row one for headers)
        strEmailContents = ""
        For Each outlookmessage In myinbox.Items
            StartCount = StartCount + 1 'increment email count

            Set myRecipient = olns.CreateRecipient(Right(outlookmessage.SenderEmailAddress, 5))
            myRecipient.Resolve
            If myRecipient.Resolved Then
                Debug.Print myRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
            End If

            UseCol = 1 'E; previous columns hold the email header information shown above (sender, date, etc)

            FullMsg = outlookmessage.Body
            AllLines = Split(FullMsg, vbCrLf)

            For FullLine = LBound(AllLines) To UBound(AllLines)
                On Error Resume Next
              'Here is where you could decide to process only certain lines, using maybe a select case statement

                eachVal = Split(AllLines(FullLine), ":") 'for a comma delimited file
                For EachDataPoint = LBound(eachVal) To UBound(eachVal) 'load each value to an array
                    UseCol = UseCol + 1
                    ReDim Preserve EachElement(UseCol)
                    '.cells(row,column)
                    EachElement(UseCol - 1) = eachVal(EachDataPoint)
                    '.Cells(StartCount, UseCol - 1).Value = eachVal(EachDataPoint)
                Next
            Next
            On Error GoTo 0

            'Now place just the selected data into the output workbook- from the array. Not necessary if you process lines individually and paste their data directly into Excel as you go

            wks.Cells(StartCount, 1) = EachElement(1)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 2) = EachElement(2)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 3) = EachElement(3)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 4) = EachElement(4)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 5) = EachElement(5)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 6) = EachElement(6)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 7) = EachElement(7)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 8) = EachElement(8)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 9) = EachElement(9)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 10) = EachElement(10)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 11) = EachElement(11)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 12) = EachElement(12)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 13) = EachElement(13)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 14) = EachElement(14)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 15) = EachElement(15)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 16) = EachElement(16)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 17) = EachElement(17)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 18) = EachElement(18)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 19) = EachElement(19)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 20) = EachElement(20)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 21) = EachElement(21)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 22) = EachElement(22)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 23) = EachElement(23)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 24) = EachElement(24)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 25) = EachElement(25)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 26) = EachElement(26)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 27) = EachElement(27)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 28) = EachElement(28)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 29) = EachElement(29)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 30) = EachElement(30)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 31) = EachElement(31)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 32) = EachElement(32)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 33) = EachElement(33)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 34) = EachElement(34)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 35) = EachElement(35)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 36) = EachElement(36)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 37) = EachElement(37)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 38) = EachElement(38)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 39) = EachElement(39)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 40) = EachElement(40)
            wks.Cells(StartCount, 41) = EachElement(41)

        Next
    End With

    UseRow = 1
    wks.Range("E1") = EachElement

    Set myOlApp = Nothing
    Set olns = Nothing
    Set myinbox = Nothing
    Set myItems = Nothing
End Sub
```

Will appreciate immediate help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this solves your problem, but try to replace all the

```
wks.Cells(StartCount, ..) = EachElement(..)
```

with:

```
Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To UBound(EachElement)
  wks.Cells(StartCount, i) = EachElement(i)
Next
```

This may solve your problem